Screen blinking every second on Dell Latitude 5480
I recently got an old Dell Latitude 5480 from work, and thought it was an excellent opportunity to see what Linux is like on the desktop these days.
Unfortunately the screen is blinking roughly every second, which doesn't make the computer very pleasant to use.
I'm dual-booting with Windows 11, and Windows reports the graphics card is an Intel HD Graphics 620. I've found a number of tips regarding setting graphics options in the /etc/default/grub file to fix intel graphics flickering, and I think these are the ones I've tried without any effect:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_psr=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_psr=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=4"

Also, these fixes seem to be for more random and intermittent screen flickering and artifacts. I haven't found anything regarding the periodical screen blinking I'm experiencing.
I've also tried adjusting the resolution and refresh rate of the screen to no avail.
Any ideas?
